# I would like to know how to plot 2 coordinate axis on top of one another

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams

[image]

here is the code along side the frames i currently have

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=3,
    tdplot_main_coords,
    axis/.style={->,black,thick},
    vector/.style={-stealth,red,very thick}]

%standard tikz coordinate definition using x, y, z coords
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

%tikz-3dplot coordinate definition using r, theta, phi coords
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{.8}{55}{60}

%draw axes
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$y$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$z$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=3,
    tdplot_main_coords,
    axis/.style={->,black,thick},
    vector/.style={-stealth,red,very thick},
    vector guide/.style={dashed,red,thick}]

%standard tikz coordinate definition using x, y, z coords
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

%tikz-3dplot coordinate definition using r, theta, phi coords
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{.8}{55}{60}

%draw axes
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$y'$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$z'$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$x'$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you already tried something on your own? If yes, please share it with us in a form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): we'd be happier to improve your work, rather to develop an alien solution from scratch all by ourselves. We're a bit lazy: help us help you! `(-:`

Comment: Hi, welcome! Have you done anything with TikZ (or other similar packages) before? Here is a similar example, albeit a bit more complex: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345721/inertial-and-local-vertical-local-horizontal-reference-frames-using-tikz Edit: by the way, if you look at the TikZ manual, the first tutorial teaches you pretty much everything you need to draw that, I think.)

Comment: I have tried TikZ before but not with much luck, i shall have a look at the TikZ manual and see if that helps.
I have managed to get two coordinate systems just not on top of one another. I shall attach what I have already got.
many thanks

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots. It's (almost) hopeless if you want to modify and test the code. Copy-paste the code directly into your post, then select it and hit the button marked `{}`. Edit; but you need both coordinate systems in the same `tikzpicture`.

Comment: ok will do one moment, apologies

Comment: right I see. I have now managed to get them both in the same tikz picture

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility. Put both coordinate systems in the same `tikzpicture`, and for the second one, draw it using relative coordinates (`+(x,y,z)` instead of `(x,y,z)`, means it relative to the previous coordinate). So to move the second coordinate system around, you only need to change the coordinates of `O2`.

And to draw things in the `O2` system, you can use the same coordinates as for the `O` system, and add `shift=(O2)` in the path options as I did below with `\draw[vector,shift=(O2)] (0,0.5,0) -- (0,0.5,0.7) node[left,black] {velocity $\mathbf{v}$};`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=3,
    axis/.style={->,black,thick},
    vector/.style={-stealth,red,very thick},
    vector guide/.style={dashed,red,thick}]

%standard tikz coordinate definition using x, y, z coords
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

%draw axes
\draw[axis] (O) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$y$};
\draw[axis] (O) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$z$};
\draw[axis] (O) -- (0,0,1) node[right]{$x$};

% modify this for position of second system
\coordinate (O2) at (-0.05,0,0.7);

%draw axes with relative coordinates
\draw[axis] (O2) -- +(1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$y'$};
\draw[axis] (O2) -- +(0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$z'$};
\draw[axis] (O2) -- +(0,0,1) node[above]{$x'$};

\draw[vector,shift=(O2)] (0,0.5,0) -- (0,0.5,0.7) node[left,black] {velocity $\mathbf{v}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I shall adjust the second system accordingly and it should be perfect